# Assign a random background.color to objects with random ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, random, jquery-data

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Adnaves/fVtVL/)

I have created a button where a "person" is created every time you click on it. The person has a random ID (not a unique, I know). The next step for is to assign each of the people a random background color when they are created.

What I've accomplished so far is that every time a new person is created, all of the people changes their color:

```
$('#BtnCreatePerson').click(function(){
 var sPersonName = $('#PersonName').val();
 var sPersonLastName = $('#PersonLastName').val();
 var sPersonAge = $('#PersonAge').val();
 var sPersonGender = $('#PersonGender').val();
 var sColor = GetMeARandomColor();

 var iRandomId = GetRandomNumber(999999, 99999999999);

 var iDivPersonId = $(this).attr('id');
 $('.Person').data('current-elem-id', iDivPersonId, oPerson);

 var oPerson = new Person();
 oPerson.setId(iRandomId);
 aPeople.push(oPerson);
 console.dir(aPeople);


$('.PersonContainer').append('<div id="'+iRandomId+'" class="Person" title="'+sPersonName+'" ></div>')
$('.Person').data('current-elem-id', iDivPersonId, oPerson).css('background-color', sColor);

$('.Person').draggable();                     

});
```

The random color function:

```
function GetMeARandomColor()
{
var aEverything = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
var sTheColor = "#";
for(i=0; i < 6; i++)
{
   iRandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()* 16);
   sTheColor += aEverything[iRandomNumber];
   //console.log(sTheColor);
}  
return sTheColor;
}
```

You can check the whole code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Adnaves/fVtVL/

The new person should have a random color, and that color should never change again. I hope that you can help me to get it working, but also to understanding how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it because you're referring to the new person as class .person rather than by id?
So it changes the color for all person divs, not just the newly created one?

Change

```
$('.Person').data('current-elem-id', iDivPersonId, oPerson).css('background-color', sColor);
```

to

```
$('#'+iRandomId).data('current-elem-id', iDivPersonId, oPerson).css('background-color', sColor);
```

This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/fVtVL/6/

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm glad that your enjoying it. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change to following lines of code to reference the ID you set to the new div, and not the Person class (As it currently is) :

From :

```
$('.Person').data('current-elem-id', iDivPersonId, oPerson).css('background-color', sColor);

$('.Person').draggable();
```

To :

```
$('#' + iRandomId).data('current-elem-id', iDivPersonId, oPerson).css('background-color', sColor);

$('#' + iRandomId).draggable();
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the class .Person. But each of your personnage has the same class. Use the id to select your element : http://jsfiddle.net/fVtVL/7/

```
$('#BtnCreatePerson').click(function(e){
    var sPersonName = $('#PersonName').val();
    var sPersonLastName = $('#PersonLastName').val();
    var sPersonAge = $('#PersonAge').val();
    var sPersonGender = $('#PersonGender').val();
    var sColor = GetMeARandomColor();
    // Memory
    var iRandomId = GetRandomNumber(999999, 99999999999);

    var iDivPersonId = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#"+iRandomId).data('current-elem-id', iDivPersonId, oPerson);

    var oPerson = new Person();
    oPerson.setId(iRandomId);
    aPeople.push(oPerson);
    console.dir(aPeople);
    // Layout
    $('.PersonContainer').append('<div id="'+iRandomId+'" class="Person" title="'+sPersonName+'" ></div>')
    $("#"+iRandomId).data('current-elem-id', iDivPersonId, oPerson).css('background-color', sColor);
    //.data( element, key, value )
    //$(e.target).css('background-color', sColor);
    $("#"+iRandomId).draggable();                     

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('.Person')
```

Use

```
var $person = $( '.Person#' + iRandomId )
```